# Cannot send SMS through PHP API when hosted on OpenShift by Redhat

Tags: php, sms, openshift, sms-gateway

I have the following script which I used to send mobile verification sms through a third party sms gateway.

```
   <?

$code      = rand(100000, 999999);
$mobilenum = "+919898989898";
$data      = '{"accountId": "xxxxxxxxxx","apiKey": "xxxxxxxxx","dndType": "transactional","smsType":"normal","senderId": "xxxxxx","to": "' . $mobilenum . '","templateId": "xxxxxxxx","placeholders": {"code": "' . $code . '"}}';
// Create a curl handle to domain 2
$url       = "https://api.smsowl.in/v1/sms";
$ch        = curl_init($url);



curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

//we want to get result as a string
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
//if servers support is and you want result faster, allow compressed response
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "Content-type: application/json"
));
//configure a POST request with some options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
//put data to send
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

echo "status code :" . $status;

//execute request
$result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

//show response form domain 2 to client if needed
//echo $code; 

//print_r(apache_response_headers());



?>
```

The script used to work fine when it was hosted on hostgator server 2 months ago. But recently I started working on the application again and hosted it on OpenShift by RedHat since the hostgator service period ended. This script doesn;t work there. status code returns 0. `curl_error()` returns null and `$result` also returns `null`.
Please help.

Comment: Use `curl_error()` to find the problem after the call.

Comment: it returns null. Also the `curl_getinfo()` returns 0

Comment: You're getting the status code *before* making the request. You should fix that and see what happens.